# When a word can refer to two things

Tags: single-word-requests

So for example someone works at a juice bar and they say *Did the juicer come today?*
which could refer to the person who makes the juice or the juicer machine.

What is this called when a word could describe two things?

Example :

> *Juicer* is _____ in the above sentence.

Comment: I added an example sentence as it's mandatory for SWRs. If I've misunderstood what you want, please revert my edit RLicens.

Comment: Homonyms are words which are spelled and pronounced the same but have different meanings.

Comment: [@NigelJ](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/425148/when-a-word-can-refer-to-two-things#comment1018318_425148) That sounds like the basis for an answer along the lines the OP is [thinking](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/425148/when-a-word-can-refer-to-two-things#comment1018279_425150). Here's a [link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/homonym) to a dictionary entry for your convenience.

Comment: What’s the difference between homographs and homonyms?

Answer (score 1):

> **Ambiguous**
>   1. adjective.
>   If you describe something as ambiguous, you mean that it is unclear or confusing because it can be understood in more than one way.
>   *This agreement is very ambiguous and open to various interpretations.
>   The Foreign Secretary's remarks clarify an ambiguous statement issued earlier this week.*
>   https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ambiguous

Comment: I think I found the word, homograph. It is ambiguous I agree http://www.grammar.net/same-word-different-meaning

Comment: @RLicens you should add this as an answer; it is ok to answer your own question on this site.